# Information in the HEADER which can not be changed/altered

Tags: security, browser, header, http-headers

What are the filed in the header which will be always present [99% atleast] and can not be altered ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "can not be altered", and why you have tagged this "security"?

Comment: i tagged it with SECURITY coz HEADER have something to do with security, i think. 'can not be altered' i tried to mean which part of header a user can not change

Comment: "Can not be altered" how? With JavaScript?

Comment: @ Matt Ball i would recommend you FF addon WebDeveloper and Header Tool and User Agent Switcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request. Everything else is optional. Host header is mandatory if using HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) this header fields is not modifiable by javascript:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Cookie
- Cookie2
- Content-Transfer-Encoding
- Date
- Expect
- Host
- Keep-Alive
- Referer
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- User-Agent
- Via
- Proxy-*
- Sec-*

Comment: But they also are not present. Using the simplest HTTP client named 'telnet', one can request google's homepage using one line and terminating headers with 2 empty lines: GET / HTTP/1.0